# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Issue - The maximum entity size has been reached or exceeded for Topic

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, service-bus

I am having an issue when starting a workflow. I receive an error message stating:

> Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow

Upon investigation of the logs I discovered the following error message:

> Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowQuotaExceededException: Cannot start more instances because the size of the topic has exceeded the quota limit.

I've had a look in Event Viewer and found more detailed error information:

> Error processing management request. Method: POST, RequestUri: http://SERVERNAME:12291/NotificationManagement/$Notifications/?$expectedScopeRevision=0, Error: System.OperationCanceledException: The maximum entity size has been reached or exceeded for Topic: 'WORKFLOWDEFAULTNAMESPACE:TOPIC:SHAREPOINT/DEFAULT/0E64F02E-16DC-4276-B2E3-56677368A77F/1670A56B-743C-419A-803E-9627209B1438/WFTOPIC'. Size of entity in bytes:6547030977, Max entity size in bytes: 6442450944.
>
> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QuotaExceededException: The maximum entity size has been reached or exceeded for Topic: 'WORKFLOWDEFAULTNAMESPACE:TOPIC:SHAREPOINT/DEFAULT/0E64F02E-16DC-4276-B2E3-56677368A77F/1670A56B-743C-419A-803E-9627209B1438/WFTOPIC'. Size of entity in bytes:6547030977, Max entity size in bytes: 6442450944.
>
> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: The maximum entity size has been reached or exceeded for Topic: 'WORKFLOWDEFAULTNAMESPACE:TOPIC:SHAREPOINT/DEFAULT/0E64F02E-16DC-4276-B2E3-56677368A77F/1670A56B-743C-419A-803E-9627209B1438/WFTOPIC'. Size of entity in bytes:6547030977, Max entity size in bytes: 6442450944.

I have found a [blog on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2013/07/21/service-bus-error-the-maximum-entity-size-has-been-reached-or-exceeded-for-topic/) with the same issue however they are using Azure Service Bus as opposed to Service Bus for Windows. They suggest adjusting the TTL for the topic to 2 days but I have been unable to find out how to do this or if this will even help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running SB 1.0 CU1 + WFM 1.0 CU3?

Comment: Service Bus 1.0 + Workflow Manager 1.0 using the offline install guide [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj906604)

Comment: Right, but at what patch level? Can you patch to SB CU1 and WFM CU3?

Comment: Product Version number for Microsoft.Cloud.ServiceBus.dll – 2.0.20922.0
Product Version number for Microsoft.Workflow.Service.dll- 1.0.20922.0
Would updating to SB CU1 and WFM CU3 resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

We were facing the same issue, we solved this by changing the following parameters (Power Shell).
In our case, it was caused by very large workflows processing in parallel.

**ServiceBusTopicSizeQuotaInBytes:**

```
Set-WFServiceConfiguration -ServiceUri "https://workflow-service-url:12290" -Name ServiceBusTopicSizeQuotaInBytes -Value 18737418240
```

**ServiceBusMaxTopicSizeInMegabytes:**

```
Set-WFServiceConfiguration -ServiceUri "https://workflow-service-url:12290" -Name ServiceBusMaxTopicSizeInMegabytes -Value 30720
```

**WorkflowServiceMaxLoadedInstances:**

```
Set-WFServiceConfiguration -ServiceUri "https://workflow-service-url:12290" -Name WorkflowServiceMaxLoadedInstances -Value 20
```

After changing the parameters, you may run "Register-SPWorkflowService" again:

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://site-url" -WorkflowHostUri "http://workflow-service-url:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp -force
$site = Get-SPSite("http://site-url")
$proxy = Get-SPWorkflowServiceApplicationProxy
$svcAddress = $proxy.GetWorkflowServiceAddress($site)
Copy-SPActivitiesToWorkflowService -WorkflowServiceAddress $svcAddress -Credential $credential -Force $true
$proxy = Get-SPWorkflowServiceApplicationProxy
$site = Get-SPSite("http://http://site-url")
$proxy.GetWorkflowServiceAddress("http://site-url")
```

*Finnaly, restart the services (Workflow Manager and Service Bus):

```
NET STOP WorkflowServiceBackend
Stop-SBFarm
Start-SBFarm
NET START WorkflowServiceBackend
```

- Check  the current value for each parameter using "Get-WFServiceConfiguration"
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680843%28v=azure.10%29.aspx

Regards,
Tiago De Faveri